# How could I manage the position of those <p> and <div> elements so they will be displayed as I need them to be?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, positioning

First of all, here a link to my CodePen: `https://codepen.io/mikaelssol/pen/qrvRKL`

As you can see in the link above, I have three `<div id="menu">` elements with "maroon" as background color. They are:

1) `<div id="menu">Fish</div>`
2) `<div id="menu">Chicken</div>`
3) `<div id="menu">Beef</div>`

The `<div id="menu">` elements are target with the following CSS:

```
div#menu {
width: 150px;
height: 90px;
background: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

I also have three `<p>` elements each of them target with the following CSS:

```
p {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #A52A2A;
width: 90%;
height: 150px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: Helvetica;
color: white;
position: relative;
}
```

The end result I've trying to achieve is to have the three `<div>` elements in blue color positioned `0px` from top and from right, perfectly aligned to the top-right border of the `<p>` elements in maroon color. Both elements have to have the same position regardless of the size of the screen of the device or the size of the browser window. All three `<p>` must be aligned in the center of the page with their `<div>` elements aligned to the top-right border.

The result I was able to get so far is the `<div>` elements getting aligned to the HTML document instead of to the `<p>` elements. I managed to work with media queries and everything very well but the positioning of those elements is giving me a hard time. Any help is very helpful.

Comment: You should only use id's once.

Comment: May be this will help: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Answer (score 0):

I did it like so: (sorry if this conflicts with your bootstrap styles)

https://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/aJMrrw

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-box-container">
    <div class="menu-box">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <div class="item-box">Fish</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-box">
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <div class="item-box">Chicken</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-box">
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <div class="item-box">Beef</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-box {
    width: 170px;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.menu-box p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: maroon;
}

.item-box {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```